# Switching JVM in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, jvm

I am trying to load a video in JPanel using Java Swing Framework.
I am getting this Error . 
 `Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM` 
I tried finding the 64-bit SWT jars but most of the links are expired and are not working.

Some people said that I should install 32-bit JVM for this purpose.
What I want to know is 
**" Is it possible that I can switch my JVM to 32-bit ? and later can revert back ?"**.

It will save a lot of time if its possible. I am using Windows 7, 64-bit and using 64-bit JVM.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options

1) use 64 bit SWT Libraries.

2) use 32 bit JVM.

Of course you can switch from 64 bit JVM to 32 bit JVM with out modifying the Java code .

Java bytecode is platform independent, assuming you use platform independent libraries. 32

vs64 bit shouldn't matter.

But SWT library have to interact with native system function ,so the library is platform dependent.

Comment: Can You tell me the methods to switch from 64-bit jvm to 32-bit jvm ? Kindly read my question carefully. Thanks

Comment: simply install 32bit JRE

Comment: Then how to switch after installing JVM . it's the question ?